# Index for x and y are mismatched - Tensorflow

Tags: python, pandas

I'm with a (108116, 9) `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` (X_train) and a (108116, ) `pandas.core.series.Series` (y_train) train to create an estimator to my model but I'm getting this error:

```
 110     if not np.array_equal(x.index, y.index):
 111       raise ValueError('Index for x and y are mismatched.\nIndex for x: %s\n'
--> 112                        'Index for y: %s\n' % (x.index, y.index))
 113     if isinstance(y, pd.DataFrame):
 114       y_columns = [(column, _get_unique_target_key(x, column))

ValueError: Index for x and y are mismatched.
```

I noticed that my both variables have the same size but the `y_train` is starting at index 6072, while the other one starts at index 0. The error I'm getting is because of that? I tried to access `y_train[0]` and I get an error, only being possible acessing elements from 6072th position.

If this is the cause, how can I shift all elements 6072 down to 0 so they both would be the same?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create default `RangeIndex` in Series `y_train` by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
y_train = y_train.reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Sample**:

```
y_train = pd.Series([1,5,6], index=[6072, 6073, 6074])
print (y_train)
6072    1
6073    5
6074    6
dtype: int64

y_train = y_train.reset_index(drop=True)
print (y_train)
0    1
1    5
2    6
dtype: int64

print (y_train.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
y_train = y_train.reset_index(drop = True)
```

As the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) states, it resets the index, and if `drop` is `True` it doesn't keep the previous index in a new column.

Comment: Both answers are correct. Thank you so much for your help, guys! Really appreciated!!